# Update query with plus several conditions check

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have been developing an MS Access tables and Querys to control a flow of several products sold. Any time a client buy a product, he earns a cashback depending of what kind of product he bought.

I have been facing some issues when I try to identifies  the product cashback for each product sold. I have to main tables :
a) Table has information about clients, products bought and dates.
b) Table of effective cashback offered for each kind of product and each date.

Take this as example

[image: Example of cashback information]

How can I develop a Query or a VBA code that see the A table (Product kind and buy date) and returns the correct information from B table (effective cashback on such date and type of product)

Regards,

Comment: Do not post images! Please, share text data (table A and B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried joining them? I have not tested this becuase you didn't provide data.

```
SELECT 
    B.ProductKind
   , B.BuyDate
   , nz(A.Cashback) as CashBack
FROM B
     left join
     A on A.ProductKind=B.Kind
       AND B.BuyDate <= A.End_Date
       AND B.BuyDate >= A.Begin_Date
```

OR with the default

```
SELECT 
    B.ProductKind
   , B.BuyDate
   , iif(isnull(A.Cashback) , AD.CashBack, nz(A.CashBack)) as CashBack
FROM (B
     
     left join
     A on A.ProductKind=B.Kind
       AND B.BuyDate <= A.End_Date
       AND B.BuyDate >= A.Begin_Date
     ) 
     left join
     AD on AD.ProductKind='Default'
       AND B.BuyDate <= AD.End_Date
       AND B.BuyDate >= AD.Begin_Date
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It worked in "the first part", where I could find rates for categories like 14, 198 and others (see the image). Now I have many other categories that does not have specific cashbacks, so I should select the "default" rate for such date.  Any suggestion?

Comment: Added that alternative, but I must say that you could have made it easier if you provided the data in text format (usable form); and responded earlier.